# C/SSL/JQuery.ajax() client -> server connection reset, but 1 byte sent

Tags: javascript, c, ssl, openssl

## Version Info

- Libs:

  - libgnutls-openssl.so.27 (libc6,x86-64)
  - libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64)
- GCC version: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
- OS (`uname -voir`): 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Browser: Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit)

## Scenario

When opening a socket via PHP, I can connect and send data to my instance of a C SSL server and receive a response, all with no issues. However, when I attempt to connect using JQuery AJAX from a client, the connection is established, immediately closed, reopened, and finally the server receives a single byte 'G', presumably the first letter of the GET request.

This results in:

> GET https://localhost:2343/?keyReq=961ee53a75eef2e2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

being displayed in Chrome's console.

## Thoughts

I don't want to be too quick to blame the client side, but I can connect using sockets just fine. Problem is, my server needs to deal with both socket and HTTPS requests.

It's also possible that I wrote the SSL accept and reads wrong somehow, in such a way that a web client can't cope.

I would be very grateful for any advice anyone could lend me to get me going in the right direction.

## Code

### ssl_server.c (The connection bits.)

```
void datactl( SSL *ssl ) { 
/* Serve the connection - threadable */

    char buf[1024];
    char reply[1024];
    int sd, bytes, rtn;

    if( SSL_accept( ssl ) == FAIL ) {                   /* do SSL-protocol accept */
        ERR_print_errors_fp( stderr );
    }   
    else {
        crtprint( ssl );                                /* get any certificates   */
        bytes = SSL_read( ssl, buf, sizeof( buf ) );    /* get request            */
        if( bytes > 0 ) { 
            buf[ bytes ] = 0;
            char tmp[1024];
            printf("data: '%s' (%d bytes)", buf, bytes );
            procdata( buf );                            /* process data           */
            getres( buf, reply );                       /* construct reply        */
            SSL_write( ssl, reply,
                            strlen( reply );            /* send reply             */
        }
        else
            ERR_print_errors_fp( stderr );
    }   
    sd = SSL_get_fd( ssl );                             /* get socket connection  */
    SSL_free( ssl );                                    /* release SSL state      */
    close( sd );                                        /* close connection       */
}

/* main - create SSL socket server. */
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) { 

    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    int len;
    int addrlen;
    char cwd[1024];
    char crt[1024];
    char key[1024];

    getcwd( cwd, sizeof( cwd ) );

    strcpy( crt, cwd );
    strcpy( key, cwd );
    strcat( crt, "/servers/certs/server.crt" );
    strcat( key, "/servers/certs/server.key" );

    ctx = initsrvctx(); /* initialize SSL. */
    getcrts( ctx, crt, key ); /* load certs.           */
    server = startsck( PORTNUM ); /* create server socket. */
/* (PORTNUM is defined at compile time by using -DPORTNUM=#### */

    while( 1 ) { 
        struct sockaddr_in serv;
        int len = sizeof( serv );
        SSL *ssl;

        int client = accept(
            server,
            ( struct sockaddr * ) &serv,
            &len
        ); /* accept connection as usual. */

        ssl = SSL_new( ctx ); /* get new SSL state with context */
        SSL_set_fd( ssl, client ); /* set connection socket to SSL state */
        datactl( ssl ); /* service connection */
    }   
    close( server ); /* close server socket */
    SSL_CTX_free( ctx ); /* release context */
}
```

### test.php

```
<?php require('./inc/head.php'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function keyRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://localhost:2343',
        data: { hello: "hello", world: "world" }
    });
}

keyRequest();
</script>
```

## Output (The errors here are self defined.)

```
2015-02-04 15:58:14 [OPEN]  | Connection opened with client. (127.0.0.1)
2015-02-04 15:58:14 [CLOSE] | Connection with client closed.
2015-02-04 15:58:14 [OPEN]  | Connection opened with client. (127.0.0.1)
2015-02-04 15:58:14 [DEBUG] | data: 'G' (1 bytes)
2015-02-04 15:58:14 [DEBUG] | Starting data processing.
2015-02-04 15:58:14 [ERR]   | Malformed or invalid data. Code: 0x10a.
2015-02-04 15:58:14 [ERR]   | Malformed or invalid data. Code: 0x10a.
2015-02-04 15:58:14 [CLOSE] | Connection with client closed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem. When specifying the `SSL_method` to be used, I had `SSLv3_server_method()` instead of `SSLv23_server_method()`. After changing this, there were no problems with reading to the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer in C is to small, you should read until you get the end of the stream - this is ussualy specified in "Content-Length" header in the request. I advice you to read the HTTP Protocol Standard, afterwards I am sure that you will easily find the solution to your problem and the connect disconnect issue will also be solved.

Comment: Agree, the server part is written on wrong assumption that whole HTTP request line will be read at once. It's not true even for simple non-ssl sockets.  He should repeat SSL_read and parse header.

Comment: I would read the content-length header if I got more than one byte.
Assuming that my buffer is indeed too small, that doesn't explain why a read of 1024 gets only the first letter of the GET request.

Comment: because you are doing this here = SSL_free( ssl );                                    /* release SSL state      */
    close( sd );   It's not sent everything at once, it has a keep-alive and it sends data in chunks you should wait for all data, not just read and if the number of bytes received is larger than 0 close.

Comment: As for doing a second `SSL_read`, I tried that, and it read nothing. `SSL_pending`  also reported that there were no bytes to read after the initial read of only 'G'.

Comment: Please put the code where you read that in a while(true) and write the output when bytes > 0 just output the message of the request. Tell me what it says, basically it should work, your sollution didn't work because SSL_Read() after another SSL_Read() does that instantly and on the request stream is not written instantly. Also some logs from the network tab or console tab in browser would help. Another question of mine would be: Why do you do this line of code  buf[ bytes ] = 0;?